# JavaScript function sending only one post parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function to send two POST parameters, one variable and one hardcoded. However, when this function sends POST parameters, actually it sends only the first parameter and not the second. I can't figure out why is this happening
The function code is :

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {

    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "sortvalue");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params);

    var hiddenFieldMode = document.createElement("input2");
    hiddenFieldMode.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenFieldMode.setAttribute("name", "mode");
    hiddenFieldMode.setAttribute("value", "showmain");
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    form.appendChild(hiddenFieldMode);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();

}
```

I saw the POST data and it is always `sortvalue=givenvalue` and not `sortvalue=givenvalue&mode=showmain` as expected..

Answer (score 2):

Because you created an `<input2>` element.

```
var hiddenFieldMode = document.createElement("input2");
```

Change it to:

```
var hiddenFieldMode = document.createElement("input");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an element with the tag name "input2".  That's not going to be interpreted as an `<input>` element.

There's no need to use `.setAttribute()` (in *any* browser) to set the properties of your new DOM nodes:

```
var hiddenFieldMode = document.createElement("input");
hiddenFieldMode.type = "hidden";
hiddenFieldMode.name = "mode";
hiddenFieldMode.value = "showmain";
```